# Do we still need support-v4 and appcompat-v7 when we have support-design?

Tags: android, android-support-design, support-v4, android-appcompat

There is a lot of discussion about this.  Some say if I have appcompat-v7 I do not need support-v4 since appcompat-v7 already has all the classes of support-v4.  Also, that support-design already has all the classes from appcompat-v7 hence we do not even need that.  There are some answer that are many years old so things might have changed by now.  I did a test, in my project I have support-design, support-v4 and appcompatv7, after removing support-v4 and appcompatv7 I am still able to use all the classes from support-v4 and appcompatv7 by just having support-design.  Can anyone clarify this?

All I am trying to do is remove support-v4 from my project and only including the indpendent modules from support-v4 such as support-compat, support-coreui, etc. However, if support-design adds support-v4 automatically this doesn't seem possible. I have removed support-v4 from gradle and appcompat-v7 and all the classes from support-v4 are still found in my project by just keeping support-design.

Comment: You never *needed* them in the first place

Answer (score 0):

> Do we still need support-v4 and appcompat-v7 when we have support-design?

Technically, it depends on your point of view.

You don't need to specify them in your dependencies but `design` still needs all those classes at compile time and runtime. Gradle + maven take care of automatically fetching these transitive dependencies.

Here's the dependency graph of a recent version of `design` support library:

- design

  - support-v4

    - support-compat

      - support-annotations
      - android.arch.lifecycle:runtime

        - android.arch.lifecycle:common
        - android.arch.core:common
        - support-annotations
    - support-media-compat

      - support-annotations (*)
      - support-compat (*)
    - support-core-utils

      - support-annotations (*)
      - support-compat (*)
    - support-core-ui

      - support-annotations (*)
      - support-compat (*)
    - support-fragment

      - support-annotations (*)
      - support-compat (*)
      - support-core-ui (*)
      - support-core-utils (*)
  - appcompat-v7

    - support-annotations (*)
    - support-core-utils (*)
    - support-fragment (*)
    - support-vector-drawable

      - support-annotations (*)
      - support-compat (*)
    - animated-vector-drawable

      - support-vector-drawable (*)
      - support-core-ui (*)
  - recyclerview-v7

    - support-annotations (*)
    - support-compat (*)
    - support-core-ui (*)
  - transition

    - support-annotations (*)
    - support-compat (*)

(*) denotes a dependency already mentioned before.

> However, if support-design adds support-v4 automatically this doesn't seem possible.

While researching the above tree I can, to my own surprise, confirm this.

For now you can try explicitly removing `support-v4` from `design` dependencies and see where that leads you (i.e. you may crash because of missing classes).

```
implementation ('com.android.support:design:27.0.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

If you do crash import the missing libraries until you don't.

Apparently the [Android Team has fixed this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68820009) and will ship in the next support library.

Comment: So you are suggesting that 1) I do not need to add support-v4 on my gradle because it is done automatically when having support-design and 2) Since support-v4 is already added automatically to support-design, if I want to actually remove support-v4 and only add needed modules such as support-component, support-core-ui, etc I have to manually remove the support-v4 and to handle the classes I need I can manually add the modules such as support-core-ui to my gradle.

Comment: @AlbertanoSantacruz Correct in both cases. I can tell you that `design` absolutely requires `appcompat-v7`, it uses not only code but relies on Android resources as well. In the end, I think, you'll end up keeping everything except `support-media-compat`. It will depend on which parts of `design` you use.

Comment: @AlbertanoSantacruz There is a `design` fork for min SDK 21 which doesn't use appcompat-v7. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-crossport [Check out its dependencies.](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-crossport/blob/master/crossport/build.gradle)

Comment: I have excluded module support-v4 from gradle yet I can still see the following modules part of support-v4 on my list of external libraries: support-compat-26.0.1 and support-core-ui-26.0.1, however support-v4 and the other modules such as support-media-compat and support-media-utils are gone.  Why weren't they removed as well?

Comment: my min sdk is 16

Comment: @AlbertanoSantacruz Check out the dependency tree in my answer. RecyclerView needs support-compat and support-core-ui. AppCompat needs pretty much everything from support-* except media. It's OK.

Comment: I see, at the end it seems that at least until android team decides to move some of those modules as part of native dependencies, it is very limited the modules from support-v4 I can actually exclude since they are added automatically to other modules because they are needed and this is being done automatically by gradle.

Comment: @AlbertanoSantacruz Support libraries are useful even in your own code, they are not going away.

Comment: I saw this coming.  The only reason I am trying to remove unneeded modules from support-v4 was because a requirement.

Comment: @AlbertanoSantacruz Yes, "unneeded", in that regard I believe your work is successfully done.

Comment: I see that excluding support-v4 from design does remove support-fragment, since I am using min sdk 16 I should not need support-fragment am I correct?

Comment: @AlbertanoSantacruz Fragment implementation has evolved and bugs have been fixed. Support fragments mirror the latest implementation. In that sense I find support fragments superior to framework fragments. ||| If you use or plan to use FragmentActivity or AppCompatActivity, you need support-fragment. Otherwise you don't.

Comment: After excluding support-v4 from design I am not able to extend FragmentActivity(it is part of support-v4(part of support-fragment), this makes sense.  However, I am still able to use AppCompatActivity, looking into android docs this class is part of support-compat, which didn't get excluded by excluding support-v4, but some methods such as oncreateoption or onoptionsitemselected are not recognized anymore.

Comment: @AlbertanoSantacruz It will crash when you try to run it.

Comment: Indeed, it crashed.

Comment: Now, even if I exclude support-v4 from support-design, if I have support-v7 on my gradle, all the modules from support-v4 are still added.  Do I have to also exclude support-v4 from support-v7?

Comment: @AlbertanoSantacruz Checkout the graph above. appcompat-v7:27.0.2 doesn't depend on support-v4, but it depends on some of its smaller modules. *It needs them to function, keep them.* Can you explain further this, quite frankly, stupid requirement? Support libraries are meant to help you develop apps with min SDK version as low as 14 without duplicating code or writing basic code yourself. It doesn't make sense to remove it. Users don't care how your app is written, they care if it works.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by appcompat-v7:27.0.2 depends on support-v4, I meant it depends on modules of support-v4.  Perhaps I didn't explain myself.

Comment: Also that's what I was explaining, removing these dependencies might bring more headache than benefit, specially since at the end the modules that we can remove are limited.